# facebook oauth can't logout user who doesn't accept permissions

Tags: php, javascript, facebook, oauth, facebook-oauth

I have a facebook application that runs in a kiosk at my restaurant, it allows users to check-in.  That works great, if they log in and accept the permissions needed, it then lets them logout when they are done without the slightest problem.

If however they don't accept the permissions no method of logging them out will work.  I have tried everything I can think of and every post I could find on stackoverflow.

How can I log the customer out if auth doesn't have the permission from the user?

I have reported this to facebook using the bug report, they have stated that they are looking into it.  Just hope one of the geniuses on here had an idea.

Comment: I'm not sure if I fully understand what you are talking about... Do you mean that the user pressed cancel when prompted to authorize your application or on an extended permission dialog?

Comment: They pressed cancel when prompted to authorize.

Comment: I'm having the same issue with you. Have you found any solutions?

Comment: No Jako, there doesn't appear to be any solution to this problem. I created a bug report on facebook and the person they assigned it to placed it under wishlist.  So this doesn't appear to be at this time a solvable problem.

Comment: I found your bug on Facebook and added myself to the repro list. I seriously hope Facebook does something about this.

Comment: I just wanted to update everyone, facebook will not be fixing this bug.  They have flat out denied to solve this problem.  There are works arounds, but they require installing plugins into firefox or chrome and then only using those browsers.